# Is it possible to render one single pixel in a WebGL animation?

Tags: javascript, animation, graphics, webgl

I'm looking at the animations at https://www.shadertoy.com

Is is possible to display only one specific pixel from such animations?

So theoretically the full animation is running and being calculated, but only one single pixel from an arbitrary X,Y display point is being displayed i.e. pseudocode:

- startAnimation(filenameOfAnimation, X, Y)

So it plays the animation but displays only the pixel as point X,Y

Why, you ask?  Imagine a very large digital sign composed of a number of raspberry pi devices for example, each Raspberry Pi has its own tiny OLED display that represents one pixel of the whole animation.  I would like to be able to play that animation across all of the Raspberry Pi devices.

Comment: Since raspi are quite low end devices, the best might be to calculate the whole animation on a master device, then make it stream its output (e.g [canvas.captureStream](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCanvasElement/captureStream)), then let your Raspi grab this stream as video (you might need a gateway like [janus](https://github.com/meetecho/janus-gateway)) and finally let your raspis draw only the pixel they want from this video using a 2d context. But honestly, why do you even go through web APIs?

Comment: Sure it is, all it needs is setting the `viewport` accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Actually what is interesting is that the code on shadertoy is running as a fragment shader. This means that the code that you see is actually being used to calculate each pixel. When you see the fragCoord variable being used, that is referring to the individual pixel being displayed. If you wanted to calculate an individual pixel value, you already have the code there. Just plug in the pixel you want and there you go! You could give each device the code and assign it a pixel to simulate. Then plug that pixel into the code and there you go!